# How to get data every 5 seconds in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, scada

I want to filter the data for example 5 seconds. As you can see at the photo "Here is the table I want to get" I post below, some of the data are updating every milliseconds, I want to eliminate that to every five seconds for be able to plot the data neatly. Please see " Here is the chart I am having trouble" photo.

This is the query.

```
USE [TrendWorkx_Demo]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getdata]
    @dateselectedfrom datetime,
    @dateselectedto datetime
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @datefr datetime
DECLARE @dateto datetime

--SET @datefr = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), @dateselectedfrom, 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8),'00:00:00', 108))
--SET @dateto = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), @dateselectedto, 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8),'00:00:00', 108))

--select @date
truncate table dbo.gtable

--create table gtable ([Date/Time] datetime, X1 decimal(8,2), X2 decimal(8,2), Y1 decimal(8,2))

insert into dbo.gtable (Sample_Value_1,Sample_TDate_1)
SELECT Sample_Value_1, Sample_TDate_1 FROM [dbo].[MyTable1_1]  where Sample_TDate_1 between /*'2018-04-21' and '2018-04-22'*/@dateselectedfrom and @dateselectedto and Sample_Value_1 > -100 order by Sample_TDate_1 desc

select * from dbo.gtable order by Sample_TDate_1 desc

END
```

I want it to be almost the same as the third photo.

[image: Here is the table I want to get]

[image: /Here is the chart I am having a trouble]

[image: Expected result]

Comment: please show the expected result and your query

Comment: Yes, if that's your existing data, what's the "improved" data you want to have? Please add it to the question.